# How can I fix the Na/NaN function evaluation error

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape

I trying to ran a code using a newick tree, the tree plots but does not want to run a chronopl function.

I have run the code on a bigger data set and the code worked with no issues, however, when I run the code on the subset of the same data set, I get an error.

This is the code I am running (`Larkie` is the name of my file).

```
etal <- chronopl(Larkie, 0, age.min = 1, age.max = NULL,
                  node = "root", S = 1, tol = 1e-8,
                  CV = FALSE, eval.max = 500, iter.max = 500)
```

> Error:
> Error in nlminb(c(ini.rate, ini.time[unknown.ages]), function(p) minusploglik(p[EDGES],  :
> NA/NaN gradient evaluation
> In addition: Warning message:
> In nlminb(c(ini.rate, ini.time[unknown.ages]), function(p) minusploglik(p[EDGES],  :
> NA/NaN function evaluation

Comment: It has tried to evaluate the gradient at a singularity. Look for any places in your code for function or its gradient where there is term with a division by a denominator that could evaluate to zero.

Comment: It turns out that tol as defined as " 
the value below which branch lengths are considered effectively zero" is where my problem is, the value I used is the default one, but I do not have any idea how to estimate it.